# Javascript: Target image Id to display message

Tags: javascript

I've attached an onclick event on two images. I would like to display a different message for each image. How do I create an if/else statement to display one message "You Liked this Cat!" if one image is clicked and the other "You Didn't Like this Cat!"

```
<img src="black_cat.jpg" alt="Profile Pic" height="300" width="300" id="profile_pic"></img>
    <img src="white_cat.jpg" alt="Profile Pic" height="300" width="300" id="next_profile"></img>
    <img src="" alt="Swipe Left" height="150" width="150" id="swipe_left" onclick="hide_profile(); show_profile();"></img>
    <img src="" alt="Swipe Right" height="150" width="150" id="swipe_right" onclick="hide_profile(); show_profile();"></img>
    <p id="display_message"></p>

function hide_profile() {
    document.getElementById("profile_pic").style.visibility = "hidden";
}

function show_profile() {
    document.getElementById("next_profile").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("next_profile").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("profile_pic").style.display = "none";

    document.getElementById("display_message").innerHTML = "You Liked this Cat!";
}
```

Comment: Where's the click event? I'd be tempted to add a `data-message="You liked this Cat!"` attribute to your image and pass that to the click event.

Comment: I'm assuming they put it inline in the HTML...

Comment: I'm with @putvande. Keep the meta with the element, and pull it using the onclick. You could even still do it inline. See my answer below.

Comment: I've edited the code to include the html

Comment: `<img/>` is self-closing, therefor `</img>` is not necessary and even invalid.

Comment: @putvande What about `<img>`? Is that valid in HTML5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the HTML element you can pass its ID

```
<img onclick="functionName(this.id)">
```

And in Javascript:

```
function functionName(clicked_id){
    if(clicked_id == "cat"){
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: What about just directly passing in the message to the function? If that is all OP wants?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to add some attribute (e.g. id or rel) to your image tags and assign some unique value to them so you can identify it onclick event handler and show message accordingly.

Or rather pass some param with onclick function.

I am providing code pressuming used with jQuery.

```
<IMG SRC='IMG1.jpg' id='1' onclick='updatepic(1)'>
```

Javascript function

```
function updatepic(id) {
if(id==1) {
//change the innerhtml for pic 1
}
else {
//change the innerhtml for pic 2
}
}
```

Comment: This has zero jQuery.

Comment: OP didn't tag jQuery, just JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

**Pass the text to the `show_profile` function.**

Try this code:

```js
function hide_profile() {
  document.getElementById("profile_pic").style.visibility = "hidden";
}

function show_profile(message) {
  document.getElementById("next_profile").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("next_profile").style.visibility = "visible";
  document.getElementById("profile_pic").style.display = "none";

  document.getElementById("display_message").innerHTML = message;
}
```

```html
<img src="black_cat.jpg" alt="Profile Pic" height="300" width="300" id="profile_pic"></img>
<img src="white_cat.jpg" alt="Profile Pic" height="300" width="300" id="next_profile"></img>
<img src="" alt="Swipe Left" height="150" width="150" id="swipe_left" onclick="hide_profile(); show_profile('You Liked this Cat!');"></img>
<img src="" alt="Swipe Right" height="150" width="150" id="swipe_right" onclick="hide_profile(); show_profile('You Didn\'t Like this Cat!');"></img>
<p id="display_message"></p>
```